# How to get unwatched videos from mysql tables for a specific user

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 mysql tables: *courses*, *users*, and between them table called *users_courses* represents the seen courses by users.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFCRp.png) as this image shows.

I want to get all courses that not seen yet for a specific user. Example: I want to get all courses that not seen by the user name 'omar'.

I have tried several queries but no one returning the correct result. !

This on gives all unwatched courses for all users not specific user !

```
SELECT cources.crs_id, cources.crs_name
FROM cources 
LEFT JOIN user_courses ON cources.crs_id = user_courses.crs_id
LEFT JOIN users ON user_courses.u_id = users.u_id
WHERE user_courses.crs_id IS null
```

Comment: `WHERE .... AND users.u_id = Y`. `users` should be as the `FROM` table and left joins after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WHERE ... NOT IN ..` nested query, like this:

```sql
SELECT cources.crs_id, cources.crs_name
FROM   cources 
WHERE  cources.crs_id NOT IN (
    SELECT user_courses.crs_id
    FROM   user_courses 
    WHERE  user_courses.u_id = USER_ID
)
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, Just I removed the duplicated column in nested query. and the result comes true :) Thanks for your help bro.